# Convergence and Limits of Sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ be two sequences recursively defined as follows: $x_1=a\geq0,y_1=b\geq0$
$$x_{n+1}=\sqrt{x_ny_n}, y_{n+1}=\frac{x_n+y_n}{2}, n\geq1$$
Prove that $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ are convergent and that
$$\lim{x_n}=\lim{y_n}$$

Comment: It's a partial duplicate. I don't think the answer requested here is given there. However, there is a proof that $b_n\leq b_{n+1}\leq a_{n+1} \leq a_n$ which shows that the sequences converge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We always have $x_n\leq y_n$ by the AM-GM inequality, so $x_n\leq x_{n+1}\leq y_{n+1}\leq y_n$, but since
$$ y_{n+1}-x_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{y_n}-\sqrt{x_n}\right)^2 $$
we have that $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and $\{y_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ are two monotonic sequences converging towards the AGM of $a$ and $b$. Also see [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic%E2%80%93geometric_mean).